# Ordinary logistic regression correctly applied/ is the model correct to answer my question

Tags: r, logistic, ordered-logit, polr

I am trying to model the following and would be happy about input/if its correct.

I want to compute a model that checks on differences between Statuses between data sets plotted here on the graph:
The question is: are there significantly more poor/moderate/good statuses in one data origin, in comparison to the other origin.

[image: Data to be modelled]

my data format is the following:

```
> head(data$Nutritional.Status)
[1] Moderate       Moderate       Moderate       Poor-very poor Moderate       Moderate      
Levels: Good Moderate Poor-very poor
> head(data$Nutritional.Status.olr)
[1] 2 2 2 3 2 2
Levels: 1 2 3
> head(data$Data.origin)
[1] IR.recent IR.recent IR.recent IR.recent IR.recent IR.recent
Levels: IR.historic IR.recent UK
```

I have tried to compute an ordinal logistic regression` from [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/multinomial-ordinal-logistic-regression/):

```
> data$Data.origin <- as.factor(data$Data.origin)
> m <- polr(data$Nutritional.Status.olr ~ Data.origin, data = data, Hess=TRUE)
> summary(m)
Call:
polr(formula = data$Nutritional.Status.olr ~ Data.origin, data = data, 
    Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
                       Value Std. Error t value
Data.originIR.recent  1.2417     0.4716   2.633
Data.originUK        -0.8151     0.4362  -1.869

Intercepts:
    Value   Std. Error t value
1|2 -0.2478  0.4251    -0.5831
2|3  1.4957  0.4339     3.4475

Residual Deviance: 895.0317 
AIC: 903.0317 
(428 observations deleted due to missingness)
> ctable <- coef(summary(m))
> ctable
                          Value Std. Error    t value
Data.originIR.recent  1.2417349  0.4716366  2.6328213
Data.originUK        -0.8150987  0.4361647 -1.8687866
1|2                  -0.2478473  0.4250569 -0.5830922
2|3                   1.4957495  0.4338635  3.4475116
> p <- pnorm(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
> ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value" = p)
> ctable
                          Value Std. Error    t value     p value
Data.originIR.recent  1.2417349  0.4716366  2.6328213 0.008467888
Data.originUK        -0.8150987  0.4361647 -1.8687866 0.061652505
1|2                  -0.2478473  0.4250569 -0.5830922 0.559831226
2|3                   1.4957495  0.4338635  3.4475116 0.000565776
> ci <- confint(m)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
> ci
                          2.5 %     97.5 %
Data.originIR.recent  0.3241307 2.18429517
Data.originUK        -1.6670721 0.05759485
> exp(coef(m))
Data.originIR.recent        Data.originUK 
           3.4616139            0.4425956 
> exp(cbind(OR = coef(m), ci))
                            OR    2.5 %   97.5 %
Data.originIR.recent 3.4616139 1.382828 8.884384
Data.originUK        0.4425956 0.188799 1.059286
```

I am not sure why IR.historic is not mentioned anymore anywhere in the outputs? Data IR historic has way less points overall due to the nature of the sample collection, maybe it was excluded therefore?

see here my data summarized:

```
> counts2 <- table(data$Nutritional.Status, data$Data.origin)
> counts2
                
                 IR.historic IR.recent  UK
  Good                    12        12 251
  Moderate                 4        37 106
  Poor-very poor           7        34  36
```

Is my final output to read/present to ctable telling me the IRrecent origin has significantly more 3 than 1&2 in comparison to UK? That is my desired outcome

Comment: Welcome to CV, Sofia.  The duplicate, although it poses a different question, has a nice answer that explains what is going on.

Comment: Thank you very much for connecting the other post, that explains why one origin is dropped. I will relevel it soon, probably for me it makes sense to have IR.recent as reference, as those are the differences i am mostly interested to detect.

I am still not sure though, do I use the correct model? I am not really interested in differences from 1-2 2-3, I am interested in the differences between origins 1-1-1, 2-2-2. 3-3-3. Is that answered in the first part of the model output and i can just disregard the second half of the modeloutput?

Comment: Testing for differences that are not automatically tested is ordinarily accomplished after you have fit the model by using "contrast matrices."  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+contrast+test.